# Initializing a `static constexpr double` with MSVC 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, constexpr

Title says it all and both of the usual ways do not work. What am I missing?

1.

```
class Cl {
    static constexpr double PI;
};
constexpr double Cl::PI = 3.14;
```

> (26): error C2737: 'private: static double const
>   Cl::PI' : 'constexpr' object must be initialized

2.

```
class Cl {
    static constexpr double PI = 3.14;
};
```

> (26): error C2864: 'Cl::PI' : a static
>   data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const
>   integral type
>   type is 'const double'

In both attempts, the error is on the same line inside the class. I am using the VisualStudio/MSVC Nov 2013 CTP compiler.

Note that making the variable `const` is not a solution because I want to use this constant in both constexpr functions and normal functions.

Comment: 2. should work. But drop the spurious `:`.

Comment: @juanchopanza That was a copy/paste error. In my code, there is a superclass after the `:`.

Comment: Anyway, 2. should work.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but `M_PI` is already defined in `<cmath>`.

Comment: @Edward Yup, PI is just an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the tables and explanation from Stephan T. L. in this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx), the *constexpr* is indeed only partially implemented in VS Nov 2013 CTP.

> The CTP supports C++11 constexpr, except for member functions.
>   (Another limitation is that arrays aren't supported.) Also, it doesn't
>   support C++14's extended constexpr rules.

(wish to put it in comments, but no sufficient points yet)

Edit: Just to add, in Herb's [blog](http://herbsutter.com/2013/11/18/visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp/#comment-13555), there is near same question about static members, but the reply is the same as Stephan.

I think it is safe to simple say that Nov 2013 CTP not implement the required OP feature (send a bug report?) and wait for a Jul 2014 CTP or VS Next (sadly).

Comment: +1 good answer (ironically, the use case from the OP isn't exactly covered by the exceptions, really, but hey, we can't expect an exhaustive list of broken features in the MSVC compiler! (Save trees)

Comment: Agree to @sehe comment, we don't have all the `do`s and `don't`s of what was really working, so we are on a gray zone here (without a proper answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can't really "initialize" a constexpr. As the keyword implies, it's a constant expression, not a variable.

It seems you just want to use `const` here.

The compiler in the second example just points out that you can't make all types const-expr.

**Update**: This appears to be a MSVC limitation.

- GCC http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/009b60ebda296730  and
- Clang http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b4e587450016441

are happy to oblige.

Indeed, the [C++11 support page mentions:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) ***no `constexpr` support*** in MSVC2010-2013

Comment: Sure, but 3.14 is a constant variable, right? I want to use it in a constexpr function.

Comment: ^ see edit. It's a literal, alright, but it's not a _`non-volatile const integral type`_, as required.

Comment: So I can't declare a double constant for use in constexpr functions? That seems like an odd limitation.

Comment: I think you can, really. But apparently not MSVC. Yet?

Comment: Maybe. This isn't really an answer, though :-/

Comment: @Navin How so? I don't see what we can add, besides finding the related bug reports/feature status from Microsoft Connect?

Comment: How do you know it is a bug?

Comment: @Navin Ok, it's a bug because it's supposed to work. **[GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/009b60ebda296730)** and **[Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b4e587450016441)** are happy to oblige. I'm not in the mood to search for standards quotes on a sunday morning :)

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. I just don't want to dismiss the error until I'm sure it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Ah. Here's the smoking gun: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx says there is **no** constexpr support in MSVC. I should have known, because I use a `CONSTEXPR` define for MSVC2013 :(

Comment: I'm using the Nov2013 CTP which supposedly supports constexpr. Anyway, I guess they only implemented it in some cases.