# Is there any way to emulate compile-time double constant with MSVS2015?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, constexpr, visual-studio-2015

I am aware MSVS2013 (even the CTP) cannot handle `static constexpr double` data members, as confirmed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23454507/256138).

Now, I hoped the MSVS2015 Preview would allow me to at least use this simple construct, but alas, I get the same error. So the logical next question is: is there any way to define a compile-time double constant with MSVC2015?

Example:

```
template<typename T>
struct my_constant
{
  static constexpr const T value = 42;
}
```

This gives the error:

```
error C2864: 'my_constant<double>::value': a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type
```

Which is C++03 mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: what's the error ? Did you miss to put  the variable name after T ?

Comment: @Jagannath I did here, fixed now and error added.

Comment: Show us why the obvious alternative, `const T value = 42;` cannot work.

Comment: @Hans That won't work either, because MSVC only allows that for integral types, as the error indicates.
I need the compile time evaluation (because the real code is calculating twiddle factors, not setting a simple constant) for performance reasons. The code in question is the final version of [this FFT here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/a-simple-and-efficient-fft-implementatio/199500857).

Comment: The Preview  version isn't the final product. You can find the supported features in the [Visual C++ Team's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx) blog, including notes on what is or isn't supported yet.

Comment: Hmm, no, that works fine on VS2013.  Try it.

Comment: @HansPassant It doesn't for me: http://rextester.com/NWMTI8174

Comment: rubenvb: I think you're just not compiling with C++11

Comment: @tenfour: it's MSVC, it compiles whatever it compiles, there is no `-std` option.

Comment: @Hans Well, I don't want to create objects of everything everywhere...

Comment: It is the linker's job to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: @rubenvb MingW and/or ICC - learn it, love it, embrace it as your own. :P Though why are you wanting this FFT code? Is it for production or a toy project?

Comment: Would a `constexpr` function do the trick?

Comment: @Mike yes, I think that's what I need. Looking back at the original code, that's what was used there (probably to work around this limitation). I just wanted to simplify the code as much as possible (make a constant, well, a constant, instead of a function. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant, I think you are asking to compile without `static` and rubenvb is compiling with the `static` according to his example code, that's why the error. However that will add an extra variable to the object with the size of `int`. I would suggest, that if `42` (or any integer) is wanted across the types then why can't simply compile with `static int const value = 42;`?

Comment: @MorphingDragon I'm actually trying to convert it into a form suitable for [C++ AMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx) which "recently" got [an open source implementation on top of HSA and OpenCL](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/cppamp-driver-ng-35), making it interesting to use instead of hacking on top of OpenCL directly. So a toy project which might just turn out to be useful. But for now, MSVC is required. I might just make it with the latest release's C++11 feature set without crying too much.

Comment: @iammilind that works for an integral type, but not for floats (which is what I need in the real code). The example is just [a dumbed down version of the real problem for you guys to approach the problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Yes, I thought that you must be having the requirement of various type, but from your question, it's difficult to figure out because (1) You are using `42` and not `42.1` which would have given a slightest hint about what you want (2) It's difficult to realize how the values will be initialized in your `template class` for different types?? This lead me to think that you want a single value for all the types. For which even a global variable would have sufficed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the compiler accepts a `constexpr` member function

```
static constexpr T value() {return 42;}
```

then that should give you a compile-time constant.

DISCLAIMER: I never use this compiler, so can't test this.

Comment: I'll need to verify the code results in a constant, but at least this compiles. Thanks.