# a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

While I run `make build` for the project [DeSiNe](https://github.com/TUDelftNAS/DeSiNe), I am getting the error: `a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression`

```
$ make build
mkdir -m 755 -p obj/Algorithm
g++ -Wall -DNO_TIMER -DNO_TRACES  -O3 -funroll-loops -finline-functions -fexpensive-optimizations -Isrc -o obj/Algorithm/Algorithm.o -c src/Algorithm/Algorithm.cpp
src/Network/Link.h:44:42: error: a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression
     static const double METRIC_MIN = 1.0/DBL_MAX; // to prevent metric to be 0
                                          ^
src/Network/Link.h:45:38: error: a call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression
     static const double METRIC_MAX = DBL_MAX;
                                      ^
```

As per [Call to a constructor cannot appear in a constant-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320238/call-to-a-constructor-cannot-appear-in-a-constant-expression) if I change the code in side the `Link` class definition in `Network\Link.h` from

```
static const double METRIC_MIN = 1.0/DBL_MAX; // to prevent metric to be 0
static const double METRIC_MAX = DBL_MAX;
```

to

```
static const double METRIC_MIN; // to prevent metric to be 0
double METRIC_MIN = 1.0/DBL_MAX;
static const double METRIC_MAX;
double METRIC_MAX = DBL_MAX;
```

I receive

```
error: ‘double Link::METRIC_MIN’ conflicts with a previous declaration
double METRIC_MIN = 1.0/DBL_MAX;
```

Comment: I have referenced that question already and described the difficulties. Please read the question fully and then comment

Comment: No, you did *not* follow the answer to that question.

Comment: ahh, sorry. The definition and declaration definitely should match. So you need to use `static const double` in the declaration (presumably in a `.h` file) and `const double` in definition (in a `.cpp` file)

Comment: alternatively, you may want to use constexpr's. Certainly, if your compiler [decently supports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454507/initializing-a-static-constexpr-double) them

Comment: @immibis I did now, can you help further?

Comment: 1. _const double_ in definition. 2. Move the definition out of `.h` file, otherwise you'll get linkage errors

Comment: @sinhayash You still have not followed it. Or the code in the question is not the code you're trying to use.

Comment: @immibis can you please help me with an example?

Comment: @sinhayash Well, the answer says to put `const Type Class::Variable = Value;` in one source file (where Type, Class, etc were the actual details of that question and are different for yours), and what you did was put `Type Variable = Value;` in a header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define METRIC_MIN DBL_MIN
#define METRIC_MAX DBL_MAX
```

seems to work well

Answer (score 0):

Added in Link.cpp [See DeSiNe link above for full code please]

```
double METRIC_MIN = 1.0/DBL_MAX;
double METRIC_MAX = DBL_MAX;
```

as suggested by @immibis

Comment: Those `double` lines must  appear in a `.cpp` file, not a `.h` file, and they must be `const`

Comment: But that `.h` file is included in many files, add in all of them?

Comment: any one file, or some one specific?

Comment: actually, this answer varies depending on whether they are class members or not. It is not clear from your question

Comment: Can you see at https://github.com/TUDelftNAS/DeSiNe, as I have indicated? or tell me how to see at least?

Comment: this is getting too scrappy, I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

The other SO question's answer that you linked to was unclear about where to write the lines. I have edited it so hopefully nobody else is misled.

To fix the compilation errors in C++03, change:

```
static const double METRIC_MIN = 1.0/DBL_MAX; // to prevent metric to be 0
static const double METRIC_MAX = DBL_MAX;
```

to:

```
static const double METRIC_MIN; // to prevent metric to be 0
static const double METRIC_MAX;
```

and then in exactly one .cpp file (it doesn't matter which, so long as `Link.h` is included by that file) add the following lines at file scope:

```
const double Link::METRIC_MIN = 1.0/DBL_MAX;
const double Link::METRIC_MAX = DBL_MAX;
```

---

*However* there may be further issues.  Clearly whoever wrote this code was using a compiler with an extension that treated `DBL_MAX` as a constant expression prior to C++11. It's possible that the rest of the code relies on the value of these constants being visible in the header.

If  you fix this bug then get compilation errors from other parts of the code relating to these variables then you may have to try a different solution (which will involve more code editing).

Comment: Shall I include float.h as indicated here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/ to fix errors?

Comment: `DBL_MAX` is defined by float.h, so that should be included already. Your error messages in your question indicate that it was included already. You can add it in anyway though if you want

Comment: It is included already; can we just do it like `define METRIC_MAX DBL_MAX`? Isn't that easy to work?

Comment: Are you still having trouble with the solution I suggested? If so, what?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `#define`. The solution of that ilk would be to place `const double METRIC_MAX = DBL_MAX;` etc. outside of the class and take out the in-class definitions, but then you also have to search all the rest of the code to make sure there is no clash with other variables called `METRIC_MAX` (since you now are introducing it into a greater scope). In fact you would use some other tricks to avoid clashes. I didnt want to go into this yet unless it turns out the first solution doesn't work.